# How to skip runtime relative URLs via webpack loader/plugin?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to implement a webpack loader/plugin that transforms code to import from URLs. How can I make webpack skip these URLs and keep them as they are without throwing any errors?

For example:

```
// A loader/plugin adds the following
import { something } from "/relative-url-available-at-runtime/script.js";

// Webpack throws module not found error, this import needs to be kept untouched
```

The target library is ESM.

This has to be done via the plugin/loader and not webpack config